# using GCS bucket to receive data from customer

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like my customer to drop a file in my bucket. Reading this document https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration I understood that my customer will have an additional step of editing ACL of the file he loads before I can process the file. This is very inconvenient since I do not want to trouble my customer with overly technical matters. Is there a user friendly alternative?

For the time being I had to create a specific customer project, make a customer rep a team member with "edit" access to the project. This scenario had the unwanted side effect of granting default access to other services in the project. I had to go through the various services and find ways to limit the customer access.

Comment: how about creating an AppEngine project that allows the user to upload a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a default object ACL for your bucket to automate this process.  Use the gsutil setdefacl command to do this.